# GlutSolidCube Transparency

Tags: opengl, glut

I created a compound using glutSolidCube (walls and roof) and i also specified a color to it.
but after rendering, it shows the color + the object inside it is also visible..
how can i hide the object?  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST) is also included in init function...

```
 void drawroof(double thickness) {
    
            glPushMatrix();
            glTranslated(1.95, .5 * thickness, 3.5);
            glScaled(3.9, thickness, 1.5);
            
            glutSolidCube(1.0);
            glPopMatrix();
    }

void drawwalls()
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glColor3f(0.52f, 0.37f, 0.26f);
    glTranslated(-2.5, .8, 9);
    glRotated(-90, 1, 0, 0);
    glScaled(11, .02 * 4, 2.6);
    glutSolidCube(1.0);
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Here is the object visible from the Compound

```
void drawCylinder()

{
  drawPlaneCylinder(); //draw cylinder
  }
```

Comment: Are you using depth testing?

Comment: Yes i am using it.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed !!! Just setup the depth function place..It was in the wrong place thats y it was not working.